# Permanently change element with jquery

Tags: jquery, cookies

I have a basic on click function that adds a class to an element. It works fine but I want the class to remain for the duration of the users visit (i.e after user leaves the page and returns the class will be added to the element still without clicking). As mentioned you can do this with cookies but how?

```
$('#toursButtons li').click(function (){
    $(this).addClass("greyImage");
    console.log ( 'button was clicked' );
  });
```

Comment: if you add a class to an element via jquery, it will stay there for the duration of the users visit, unless something in your code removes/modifies it

Comment: Please clarify your issue, given the code you posted for adding the class, there is no reason why it would go away

Comment: What do you mean by 'duration of the users visit'?  Are there page refreshes during this visit?

Answer (score 0):

No you have completely misunderstood AJAX, AJAX is use to open an external file and you certainly don't need that.

Just do

```
$('#toursButtons li').click(function (){
    $(this).addClass("greyImage");
    console.log ( 'button was clicked' );
  });
```

And this will add the class `greyImage` to the element `#toursButtons li`.

And then If you want it to be their everytime the user visit the page again without the click, then you can use cookies.

**EDIT**

*With Cookies*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        if(!$.cookie("setHeight"))
        {
           $('#toursButtons li').click(function (){
               $(this).addClass("greyImage");
               $.cookie("setHeight", "1");
           });
        }
        else
        {
           $("#toursButtons li").addClass("greyImage");
        }
    });
```

Comment: I edited the question. Yes what I meant was when the user returns to that page the element will have that class still without clicking.

Comment: I hope that you are using jQuery file? The code is working fine here.

Comment: ya I have it in an external js file and using this version of jQuery `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js`